# Synonym for "cluster" in a technical context

Tags: synonyms

We're looking for a suitable synonym for **cluster** as in "*a cluster of applications*" within our enterprise architecture.

We don't want to use "cluster" itself since this can be *misunderstood* to mean a cluster of physical servers.

Our *rejected* options are

- bunch
- bundle
- set
- pack
- platform
- constellation

Edit to add more technical context:

These are **not** desktop applications or products, but elements within the overall enterprise such as a [JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) application, a [web portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_portal), a [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system#Web_content_management_systems) and so on.

What should the synonym be?

Comment: This may sound too simple but have you tried a [thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/collection) just to get started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mandatory Star Trek reference:

> Collective

Other possibilities include:

> - Array
> - Assemblage
> - Composite

There a actually quite a few that could continue to be added here, but it really depends on the extended requirements: is *'a cluster of applications'* precisely the way in which this term is to be used?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "No Star Trek References" is in the FAQ. ;-)  Although I like *collective* and I had thought of suggesting *assemblage* myself.

Comment: @Kit Well, not yet. There'd be danger of revolt if it were, methinks. Yeah, _Assemblage_ works, but it seems very exotic for this purpose.

Comment: And isn't *assemblage* already used for something?  I know *assembly* is, but it seems I've seen *assemblage* as well, maybe for an assembly of assemblies?

Comment: I like Collective, our usage is "CRM Collective", "order collective", "fault collectove"

Answer (score 4):

If they are related to each other, consider *family*.  (Also *suite*, already suggested by somebody else.)

Comment: I like that *family* implies a relationship between all components.

Answer (score 3):

The usual word used with a group of closely-related but distinct applications would be *suite*:

> Mumblesoft provides a suite of applications for managing your enterprise toasters.

Comment: *suite* would work for products, but our context is different. Please see my edit.

Comment: @JoseK: There's no reason why *suite* has to apply to the desktop. As far as I can see it could apply to your situation too. The implication is that the applications are designed to complement each other / work well together (like a [musical suite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suite), or a suite of furniture).

Answer (score 2):

The first two words I thought of were **stack** and **assembly**, but of course, these have other meanings as well.  Other than *suite*, which really sounds quite suitable to me, you might consider **[conclave](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conclave)** or **[enclave](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enclave)**, both of which refer to special groupings.

Conclave is a grouping of authorities, which is a nice implication for your products.

Enclave is a distinct group enclosed within a larger group (often within hostile territory), which is a pretty good inside joke if you have the same relationship with your enterprise architecture that we do.

Also, if you like military imagery, you might consider **regiment** or **echelon**, the latter of which I think would be particularly appropriate for tiered architecture because it implies a step-like formation.

EDIT: I also just thought of **hive**, which we used to describe our entire laboratory setup in my previous tenure as a scientist.

Comment: +1 for "stack", which to me works well for a group of pieces of software that work together to achieve a single purpose.

Comment: @JoseK I added "hive" to the list.

Answer (score 1):

There are:

> Group
>   Collection

As in "a group of applications" or "a collection of applications"

Or you could try:

> A number of applications/ a quantity of applications

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the word:

```
toolkit
```

could be used in conjunction with a modifer befitting the general range of "elements" within your system... I was thinking that a variation of "*utilities toolkit*" or "*application integration tools*" might be suitable.

Comment: *Toolkit* is a good way of suggesting that the elements are all used for specific purposes within your architecture.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd use "aggregate". It specifies a whole created from a number of (usually dissimilar) parts.

Comment: +1 I'm quite fond of aggregate.  It reminds me of concrete, which makes me think of many diverse parts making a strong whole.

Answer (score 1):

Traunch or Tranche

The word tranche is French for slice, section, series, or portion.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tranche

I worked in one organization that used the word to identify a cluster of servers used in a particular release of software. For each release there'd be a new tranche in the QA environment to support that release.

Comment: This. It may be an erudite-sounding word, but it fits.

Answer (score 0):

Since your document is a technical description of a specific software architecture, I strongly urge you *not* to look for alternate terms or synonyms. Even if they would be equivalent, English-wise, they will probably have different technical connotations. Try to use *common, established terms*.

If you're describing a set of components with built-in redundancy, either with active-passive failover or active-active load-balancing, use *cluster*. If there's possible ambiguity with a hardware server cluster, use a qualifier like *software cluster*, but don't invent new terms.

Answer (score 0):

I would not reject **set**

It covers the meaning and is easy to spell.